# Prevent RowChanged event from firing in RowChanging in .NET Datatable

Tags: .net, datatable

In our application, we are adding a row to a datatable. I would like to validate the row before it is added to the table, and if the data doesn't meet business requirements, the row does not get added.
I would think RowChanging even is where I need to add validation code. However, how do I prevent the row from being added to the DataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way you can stop a row from being added in the `RowChanging` event handler is to throw an Exception:

```
if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add) {
    if (e.Row["SomeColumn"].ToString() == "AnInvalidValue") {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't do that.");
    }
}
```

You'd obviously have to catch this exception and handle it gracefully.

A better approach would be to do your validation in the UI before attempting to add the new `DataRow`.

Comment: Good point. I ended up doing validation beforehand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose We Have a DataGridView. You must use dataGridView1_RowValidating Event. A smple code is below:

private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty==true)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString() == "")
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Student FirstName");
        }
    }
```